# Error occurs when attempting to award a bounty in Stack Overflow Team

Tags: bug, status-completed, bounty, stack-overflow-for-teams

The below error shows when I attempt to award a bounty on our SO teams site. Before this error the popup asking "Are you sure..." comes up and I click "OK". This is the first bounty we've had on our site so I do not know if it is just this question or if it would happen with other questions.

[image]

Comment: Hit F12 and open the Network Tab, then click XHR. Try to award your bounty again and you should see the request in console. Is there any message in the Response tab?

Comment: Did anyone else but me try to click the "X' :/

Comment: @Machavity with the error showing I Hit F12, opened Network Tab, clicked XHR, clicked the x to close the error, clicked on the "+50" bounty button and hit OK for the "Are you sure". The same error showed on the UI but it was beige instead of red. The response gave me https://stackoverflow.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/posts/103/vote/9

Comment: @BethWhitezel Awesome. That's a 500 error. SO broke something. So you have a bona fide bug. [Nick Craver will be with you shortly](https://twitter.com/Nick_Craver/status/996181654359236613). Provided you have Febreeze

Comment: Well I'm glad it's bona fide and not figment. How long does it take for the smell of burnt popcorn to dissipate... or should I ask that on seasoned advise?

Comment: @BethWhitezel this sounds like the perfect question for a bounty itself!

Comment: @Machavity no contact yet? Do you need contact info?

Comment: @BethWhitezel I'm not an SO Dev. Someone like Nick Craver or Adam Lear will have to fix it. But you've done the right thing in posting it as a bug

Comment: @BethWhitezel, it will take 6-8 weeks

Comment: yahhh... [6-8 weeks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514) should do.

Comment: @BethWhitezel Sorry about that. I see the error in our exception logs and will investigate ASAP.

Answer (score 2):

This should be fixed now. Please try awarding the bounty again and let me know if there are any remaining issues.

Thanks for the report, and I apologize for the inconvenience.

Comment: @Adam_Lear I am still getting the same error.

Comment: @BethWhitezel Huh. Sorry about that, will keep digging!